# Links with single/double quote or space are redirecting

Tags: php, .htaccess

Am testing on a localhost, my htaccess is as shown below:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ pages/user.php?u=$1 [NC,L]  
RewriteRule ^bookmarks pages/bookmarks.php [QSA]
```

If I type 'localhost/project/bookmarks' or 'localhost/project/user/username' I will be taken to bookmark's page or user's page.

If I added characters like '({[-,._'  php will dissect the variable, if it doesn't comply with the page's url accepted characters it will echo error.

But when ' or " or space is added,  the page will redirect instead of processing the '$_GET' request.

Book'marks or bookma'rks is redirecting to https://www.google.com/search?q=localhost%2Fproject%2Fboo%27kmarks&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb

How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not your .htaccess or your php. This is your FireFox offering you google's search services.
There are a number of ways to fix it (in FF's about:config page) but you might be best off just typing the `http` before `localhost` for local URLs.

Instead of

> localhost/project/bookmarks

type in

http://localhost/project/bookmarks

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However, if i upload the site online  for different users to access I fear not all of them will begin typing the url with http://, is the case the same for online hosted sites also.? Will users get redirected if they didn't type http:// ?

Comment: @Bishiya This is entirely up to your browser or your user's browser. You would hope that a browser would just resolve the text you type in the address bar to an IP address and connect but modern browsers will offer "features" like searching from address bar or url completion (automatically add www. and .com). Not really the features a developer needs. But having said that, any "normal" / public URLs usually resolve fine.